# document viewer control

Tags: asp.net, document, viewer

Is there any third party ASP.net document viewer controls?

1. which supports the following formats
   `.jpg/.jpeg/.bmp/.xls/.xlsx/.doc/.docx/.pdf/.tif/.tiff/.txt` etc.
2. telerik controls also allowed
3. without flash and silverlight

Comment: http://www.google.com/ ......

Comment: Actually i saw **TXText Control** but it didn't support .xls/.xlsx formats

Comment: **Accusoft**  is flash document viewer,which is not suits to my requirement

Comment: Is there any third party document viewer controls are there?

Answer (score 1):

Look at tools like http://www.vuzit.com/ and its competitors.  I'm not sure if you need to comply with any regulations or anything, but I know vuzit meets a lot of them, such as HIPAA and that sort of thing in terms of security.

It is not native ASP.NET.  It is a third-party tool, but it can be integrated very easily.  It's far from the only company on the block (though in full disclosure: I have a relationship with these guys -- I know the founders).  But check them and their competitors out and see if they meet your needs.

Comment: Is it suuport the following formats?.jpg/.jpeg/.bmp/.xls/.xlsx/.doc/.docx/.pdf/.tif/.tiff/.txt

Comment: 99% sure it does all those document types but you'd have to contact them to be certain.

Comment: is it like google docs viewer?we send documents to their server to convert

Comment: @HarikhaO it is perhaps functionally like google docs viewer, but it is meant to be a SaaS so you can use within your application more seamlessly.

Comment: i didn't get any demo from that site..

Comment: after i tried for trial version of vuzit i didn't get any private and public keys,which are required for developing like          Vuzit.Service.PublicKey = "-----";
    Vuzit.Service.PrivateKey = "----";
    Vuzit.Document doc = Vuzit.Document.Upload("E:\\ASP.NET LIFECYALE.pdf");